Title: CKEditor Image Upload Fails with "filerepository-no-upload-adapter" Error
I'm using CKEditor in my React project, and I need to enable image uploads. However, when I try to upload an image, I encounter the following error message.
I've done some research and understand that this error means that CKEditor does not have an upload adapter configured. Despite following the documentation, I can't seem to resolve this issue.
Here's what I have done so far:
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic @ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload

